# jQuery slideToggle for multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I am trying to do is have four links that each will display and hide a certain div when clicked. I am using slideToggle and I was able to get it to work with really sloppy and repetitive code. A friend of mine gave me a script he used and I tried it out and finally was able to get something to happen. However, all it does is hide the div and wont redisplay. Also it hides all the divs instead of just the specific one. Here is a jsfiddle I made. Hopefully you guys can understand what I am trying to do and help! Thanks alot.

Here is the script I'm using.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".click_me").on('click', function () {
    var $faq = $(this).next(".hide_div");
    $faq.slideToggle();
    $(".hide_div").not($faq).slideUp();
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uo15brz1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a  link to a fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/uo15brz1/7/

I changed your markup a little, adding id attributes to your divs.  The jquery, gets the name attribute from the link that's clicked, adds a # to the front, hides the visible div, then toggles the respective div.  I also added e.preventDefault to stop the browser from navigating due to the hash change.  As an aside, javascript don't require the $ prefix.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".click_me").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        var target = $("#" + name);
        if(target.is(':visible')){
            return false; //ignore the click if div is visible
        }
        target.insertBefore('.hide_div:eq(0)'); //put this item above other .hide_div elments, makes the animation prettier imo
        $('.hide_div').slideUp(); //hide all divs on link click
        target.slideDown(); // show the clicked one
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot its almost working how i intended. What I want to make happen is that only one div can show at a time. For example, I want the about me to show on load like it is and the other 3 to be hidden. If I click projects I want all the other divs to hide and that one to slide into view. Do you understand what im trying to say?

Comment: Why shouldn't js variables begin with a $? This is an extremely useful convention to indicate that a reference points to a jQuery object. It makes code more readable.

Comment: @Nick, I've edited my response so only one div is visible at a time.

Comment: @Ben, That's a good point.  I thought he was using it simply because its the naming convention for other programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/uo15brz1/2/

Basically, you need a way to point to the relevant content `<div>` based on the link that's clicked. It would be tricky to do that in a robust way with your current markup, so I've edited it. The examples in the jquery documentation are pretty good. Spend some time studying them, they are a great way to start out.